# Why my PHP script works when it is offline but not when it is online?

Tags: php, radphp

I have a PHP application created (on RentACoder) in RADPHP. When I run it from RADPHP IDE it works. However, when it is online only a small part of the interface is shown.

Any hints about what I should do to make it work?

Comment: when you say it throws no errors, have you checked in the server error log; a live web server would typically have error reporting switched off so that it wouldn't show PHP errors in the browser, but they will still be in the server logs.

Comment: you have to provide much more information to get good answers! on what system to you develop, what live environment do you have, how does your file structure look like, through what url do you access the respective sites, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
This is a bug in RadPHP.
It happens when the user edits the Font property (for any control on the form).

Answer (score 3):

> However, when it is online only a
>   small part of the interface is shown.

A missing extension? Could be anything really. Put this at the beginning of your script to make PHP more verbose:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and take it from there, I guess.

Comment: Ot better dont, if this is a live site resort to your error logs

Comment: Surely it is not a live site, since it is totally broken.

Comment: That helped a lot. I can see some errors now! Please see the original post.

Answer (score 1):

There´s not a lot of information here, so I´ll just take a wild guess: Perhaps your offline environment is case-insensitive and your online environment is not.